# Расширить один массив другим по ключу

Tags: php

Есть два массива:

```html
$arr1 = [
  'title' => 'Пример'
  'url' => 'test',
  'info' => '1'
  'active' => '0'
];

$arr2 = [
  'title' => 'required',
  'url' => '',
  'info' => 'requred'
];

//Я хочу получить в конечном итоге такой:

$arr3 = [
  'title' => [
    'content' => 'Пример',
    'empty' => 'required',
  ],
  'url' => [
    'content' => 'test',
    'empty' => '',
  ],
  'info' => [
    'content' => '1',
    'empty' => 'required',
  ]
]
```

Пытаюсь делать так, но это как-то не правильно на мой вгляд и выскакивают warning (*Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in*) в строке с if (!empty($v[$keys]) == !empty($field[$keys]))

```html
$arr3 = [];
        $keys = array_keys($arr1);
        foreach ($arr1 as $key => $v) {
            if (!empty($v[$keys]) == !empty($arr2[$keys])) {
                $arr3[$key]['content'] = $v;
                $arr3[$key]['empty'] = $arr2[$key];
            }
        }
```

Как можно переделать этот скрипт более правильно и чтобы без ошибок?

Comment: а active не нужен?

Comment: Я, честно говоря, не особо понимаю, чего вы хотели добиться таким условием. Выглядит бессмысленным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

empty не пропустит url из arr2, потому как он пуст. можно проверять, что индекс есть при помощи isset

```
    $arr3 = [];
    foreach ($arr1 as $key => $v) {
        if (isset($arr2[$key])) {
            $arr3[$key]['content'] = $v;
            $arr3[$key]['empty'] = $arr2[$key];
        }
    }
    print_r($arr3);
```